# Finding a device IP address within a different IP range from the machine IP address

Tags: python, find, ip-address

We have couple of debugging tools that look for a device and they can find IP address of the device even if it's within a different IP range of current machine.

For instance, usr-vcom cannot find all usriot Lan to serial network which accessible.

I have three USR-TCP232-304 adaptor within IP range of 10.99.33.xxx and my laptop IP address is 120.34.76.347, but usr-vcom can find all the USR-TCP232-304. They have a configuration tool that even edit the config values and change parameters including the IP address of the adaptors if you wish.

I'd like to write a python code to do a same thing, not just for USR-TCP232-304 devices, I have other equipment with similar configuration tools capability.

I can connect to the instruments and control them if I know theirs IP addresses and ports but I don't know how to search for them especially outside of the IP range of the machine that runs the code. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

import library

```
import socket 
hostname = socket.gethostname()
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname) 
print("Your Computer Name is:" + hostname) 
print("Your Computer IP Address is:" + IPAddr)
```

to obtain IP address of any range from an Hostname

2- You can find the IP address of any class and different network or IP range.
just install `Advanced IP scanner` [Get IP scanner here](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/).

3- You can also check from DHCP leases if you have router access if necessary.

Comment: My question is not about finding IP address of the machine which runs the code. Installing the third party application is not answered, it's my question in fact, that how they work.